# Fix Breadcrums when the blog archive is a page?

Tags: archive, breadcrumbs

How is possible fix a Breadcrums when the blog archive is a static page?

I want to custom the archive blog with a builder. I have create a page named blog.

But now in my breadcrums show Home > Category > Single

I want Home > Blog > Category > Single.

Is possible a solution?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it's possible. Show us your code if you want us to help

Comment: What code do you need?